# How do I push my data files to Heroku?

Tags: heroku

My app has a Postgres DB, but the initial population is done from csv files that add up to 900MB total.
The way I do this now is by setting the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable on my local computer to the Heroku Postgres DB's URL, but this takes many hours since it has to send a lot of transactions over the network. For comparison, when I load the data to my SQLite DB on my computer, it only takes about a minute.

Is there a way I can upload my data files to Heroku so I can run the script local there (with `heroku run`), to make it faster? I'd like to upload them zipped and then unzip on the server, if possible.

I've looked at [`heroku push`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push) but as far as I understand, it deploys an entire directory and not specific files.

Comment: Have you looked at importing data via PG Backups, as instructed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export? Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but my files are not PG dumps - I have a script to load the data from them and insert into the DB.